# Because TimyTimeMain depends on date_picker_timeline ^1.2.1 which depends on intl ^0.16.0, intl ^0.16.0 is required

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

```
date_picker_timeline: ^1.2.1
intl: ^0.17.0
```

Running "flutter pub get" in TimyLocalNotif...
Because TimyTimeMain depends on date_picker_timeline ^1.2.1 which depends on intl ^0.16.0, intl ^0.16.0 is required.

So, because TimyTimeMain depends on intl ^0.17.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because TimyTimeMain depends on intl ^0.17.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1

**when i make intl: ^0.16.0 i get a problem with easy_localization: ^2.3.3 package**

Answer (score 2):

You can try this steeps:

- flutter clean

then add this lines in pubspec.yaml file

```
dependency_overrides:
 intl: any
```

- flutter pub get
- flutter run

I hope solve your problem. If have not solve your problem please comment .. I will try to give another solution

Comment: i get this error Warning: You are using these overridden dependencies:                   
! intl 0.17.0